# Need Windows Command

Tags: windows, command-line, netsh

I am using this Windows command:

```
Administrator>netsh interface ipv4 add address “Local Area Connection” <IP Address> <Subnet Mask> <Default Gateway>
```

and it returns an error `not recognized as an internal or external command operable or batch file` what is wrong with this command?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the netsh program in /windows/system32 folder?. If you have it, add the system32 folder to the path environment variable, or go to that folder in your cmd and execute it directly.

Comment: Thank you for that quick response. I checked that folder and I do not have netsh in there. Now what can I do? I need this for an online class. Thank you.

Comment: I might be splitting hairs here, but I'm not sure that "MS DOS" is the correct term to be searching for here.  You're probably looking for a Windows Command Line solution.  MS-DOS is a completely different OS that pre-dates windows.

Comment: It looks like [you have smart-quotes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/25/9443404.aspx) in `"Local Area Connection"`.  Try retyping them.  Also, this is off topic for SO.  Try [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault.](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Thank you Balrog30. I believe that you may be correct. It is being used in VMWare for virtual machines and this is for a core server only. That is the command line, our book instructed us to use, so I was wondering why it did not work.

Comment: Removed the references to MS-DOS because this is all about Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of these problems:

- a path issue that can be solved by editing the path environment variable, or
- the program is not installed in your computer.

Check if the file `netsh.exe` exists in the c:/windows/system32 folder. If it is there, then open the terminal and execute the command:

```
PATH
```

You will see the whole path. Make sure that the system32 folder is in it. If it is not present then you can add it using the following command:

`PATH %PATH%;C:\windows\system32`

If you don't have the file `netsh.exe`, the Network Shell might not be installed. You can download and install it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4702).